# How to use hotkey in notepad++ webedit plugin?

Tags: html, notepad++

How to use hotkey in notepad++ webedit plugin?
what are the keyboard shortcuts to press to insert html tags??

Answer (score 6):

Install the "webedit" plugin. Which will allow you to add custom shortcuts. 
(Plugins > plugin manager).

After the program restarts, go to plugins > webedit > edit config. And either change an existing one or add a new one, (example &A=
 | ). You can remove the shortcut icons if they annoy you.

Then you go to, settings, shortcut mapper. Right now, ctl+enter is set to word completion I believe. Change that to something else (on main menu). Then go to the plugin commands tab and find your command and set it to ctl+enter. Then restart, and it should work.

http://www.graphicdesignforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=52719

Answer (score 3):

> All keyboard shortcuts can be assigned/modified using the standard Shortcut Mapper. For more information see the WebEdit.txt help file.

That's what it says in the plugin description, at least.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From the config file i got this command:

&A=<a href="#">|</a>
Div &Class=<div class="">|</div>
Div &Id=<div id="">|</div>
&Em=<em>|</em>
H&1=<h1>|</h1> etc..
So, when I pree H&1, it should be converted to <h1>|</h1>.
But when I press the commands it do not work. Is it conflicting with any other plugins? Or i'm making any mistakes?

Answer (score 3):

Setting>Keyboard Shorcut>Plugins commands
then go to

```
- WebEdit - A
- WebEdit - Div Class
- WebEdit [...]
```

and select shortcut

Answer (score 2):

I see that someone sort of answered it but I have a few things to add.

When you install WebEdit, go to the config as stated.

Go down to the [Tags] section.
Underneath all the comments, add the shortcut you want.
Here is the syntax:

```
<Tag>=<Replacement>
```

For tag, put what you want to replace. For example 'h1' (dont use the carrots).
put the = sign.
Then for replacement, put what you want "h1" to be replaced with.
Here is an example of my h1 hotkey:

`h1=<h1>|</h1>`

What the pipe character does is tell npp where to put your cursor after the replacement.

So this is how you use it now:
type h1, then press 'Alt+Enter'(by default, you can change this too), then BAM, your 'h1' will be replaced with:

`<h1></h1>` and your cursor will be sitting between the tags.

You could also do `h1=<h1>|\n</h1>` which would print the same thing but with a line break.

You can do some pretty awesome stuff with it. Saved me SO much time once I got used to it. I never type without it anymore lol.

Here is what my personal setup looks like under the [Tags] section (and I commented everything below starting with the `m=module` because it was messing with my 'p' tag and I didn't care anyways.

```
begin=<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n</head>\n<body>\n\n|</body>\n</html>
h1=<h1>|</h1>
h2=<h2>|</h2>
h3=<h3>|</h3>
h4=<h4>|</h4>
h5=<h5>|</h5>
h6=<h6>|</h6>
html=<html>\n|\n</html>
script=<script type="text/javascript">\n\t\n</script>
link=<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="|">
a=<a href="|"></a>
div=<div>
divclass=<div class="|">
divid=<div id="|">
divend=</div>
p=<p>|</p>
ul=<ul>\n\t|\n</ul>
li=<li>|</li>
header=<header>\n\t|\n</header>
nav=<nav>\n\t|\n</nav>
section=<section>\n\t|\n</section>
article=<article>\n\t|\n</article>
aside=<aside>\n\t|\n</aside>
footer=<footer>\n\t|\n</footer>
```

Remember one thing; after you edit the WebEdit, you have to restart NPP before the new tag will work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but you can use the Emmet plugin to speedup your HTML and CSS typing. you can customize your snippets to make any text.

It cames whith dozens of snippets already, you just have to type it and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You can find the file to edit in this path:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\EmmetNPP\emmet\snippets.json

It's easy to spot what you have to do.

On the plug-ins menu you will find all options that this plugin offers.

Experiment it like typing `html:5` and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Or even this `ul>li*4>a[href=page.php?id=$]{page $}`.

You will be amezed.

Answer (score -1):

Check this online [documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Keyboard_And_Mouse_Shortcuts) for keyboard & mouse shortcuts

Comment: I'm looking for shortcut command of NotePad++ webedit plugins, not for NotePad++.