# notepad++ for ASP auto complete

Tags: plugins, notepad++

Do somebody know that I want to get a plugin just like "auto complete" on Notepad++ for ASP,
I tried to add a asp.xml file in ./APIs and it's working, but how can I use it just like when I type "re" than I can choose "response", then I type ".", it will show some keywords just like "write" that I don't need to type "wr"?

as I know I can use it on Dreamweaver but I cannot found the same plugin on notepad++

Answer (score 0):

Try `WebEdit` plugin and add custom shortcuts in the config file, like:

```
wr=write
re=response
```

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209143/how-to-use-hotkey-in-notepad-webedit-plugin)